# Facet to get all keys from an object in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, faceted-search

Let's say I have the following docs:

```
{
    "title": "Some Title",
    options: {
        "key5": 1,
        "key3": 0,
        "key1": 1,
    }
},
{
    "title": "Some Title",
    options: {
        "key2": 0,
        "key3": 0,
        "key5": 1,
    }
}
```

I want to get all the keys from `options` object using facet.

If `options` was a simple array of keys as strings, I would simple use a facet like this:

```
"facets" : {
    "options" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "options"
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work in my case.

So if a `query` returns those two docs, I should get these keys: ["key5","key3","key1","key2"]

What kind of facet do I actually need?

Comment: What would you want to obtain as output of your facet?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that using a facet. 
You have 2 options -

1. Keep your current document structure and get the list of keys from the type mapping (see http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html). This brings the scheme of your type which holds all the fields encountered.
2. Change your structure. Keep the key also as a field, so your option array becomes an array of documents like:

   `"options" :

   [

   { "key" : "key1", "value" : 1},

   { "key" : "key2", "value" : 0}

   ]`

You probably will want to keep the context of the key-value pairs when searching or faceting so configure it as a nested type (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html).
Then you can facet on the "options.key" field to get a list of top keys.

Comment: Old answer I know, but I'm wondering if it's possible to facet on all key1 values, all key2 values, etc., so you get the breakdown of values for each, rather than just the list of keys. Sort of what I'm asking here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58447233/elasticsearch-faceting-for-array-of-dictionaries-with-elasticsearch-dsl-python

Comment: This is very old, today you shouldn't have a problem with aggregations (and not facets).

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly, you would want to make a `terms_facet` for each and every field in your nested options object. kind of a "wildcard facet"?

i think that there is no functionality in the facet api that allows for this kind of operation. if i am not mistaken, fields used for faceting have to be mapped, so it might be possible to extract the fields in a separate query by inspecting the index mappings.