# ElasticSearch: how to store product attributes

Tags: elasticsearch

Which way of storing product attributes is more correct in ElasticSearch?

Nested objects:

```
"attributes": [
    {
        "name": "color",
        "value": "White"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "size",
        "value": "S"
    }
]
```

Or key-value array?

```
"attributes": [
    {"color": White"}
    {"size": "S"}
]
```

Assuming that the attributes are searchable and they will be also used in faceted search (aggregation).
Each product can have different attributes, so the keys (attribute name) are not fixed.

Comment: Key Value is almost always better for searching in ElasticSearch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the first way (nested) is better since it allows to make aggregation queries even on attributes names which solves such issues:

- [ElasticSearch: count product attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255310/elasticsearch-count-product-attributes)
- [Facet to get all keys from an object in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479786/facet-to-get-all-keys-from-an-object-in-elasticsearch)
- [How to aggregate over dynamic fields in elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800545/how-to-aggregate-over-dynamic-fields-in-elasticsearch)

etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the second approach with

```
"attributes": [
  {"color": White"}
  {"size": "S"}
]
```

You are able to search directly in fields and build facets over these values.

Comment: Won't it be a problem that the set of attributes is different for each product? And how can I define the mapping of such structure?

Comment: No, this is no problem. You have to make sure that your fields, where  you want to build facets, are not analyzed. If the fields are very different, you could apply a dynamic mapping for your attributes: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-dynamic-mapping.html

Comment: I indexed the documents with key-value attribute structure, but searching doesn't work for it. So when I try to find by term "attributes.color": "Red", there's no results although they should be.

Comment: When I enumerate all attributes and specify "index: not_analyzed" for each - all works, but how can I specify this for all possible attributes mapping?

Comment: That's what I need: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html

Answer (score -1):

Dynamic mapping template solved the issue:

```
"dynamic_templates": [{
    "string_template": {
        "path_match": "attributes.*",
        "mapping": {
            "index": "not_analyzed"
         }
    }
}]
```

Comment: This is incorrect. By making your index "not_analyzed" you can't query your product attributes. https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings

Comment: @user3751385 Why can I not query the attributes? Looks like you just don't understand what "not_analyzed" means. In 99% of cases, attributes should be searched as keywords rather than text, that's why "not_analyzed" was used. And keep in mind the original question was related to ES 1.