# ElasticSearch: count product attributes

Tags: elasticsearch, faceted-search

I have a datatype 'product' which has a field 'attributes' (dynamic object).
For example, a product can contain:

```
attributes: {
    "color": "White",
    "size": "L",
}
```

another product can contain

```
attributes: {
    "color": "Black",
    "weight": "12 kg",
}
```

So the set of attributes is not fixed.

My goal is to make faceted search over all attributes of products which were found.
I found a way to manually define each attribute in 'aggregations' section:

```
"aggregations": {
    "attribute_color": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "attributes.color"
        }
    },
    "attribute_size": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "attributes.size"
        }
    )
}
```

But I don't know in advance which attributes will be found so I want to make this list dynamically.
I assume this can be done in 2 steps: find all attribute keys (color, size, weight, etc) and then make aggregation query for these fields.
So the question is how I can get all attributes keys from the search result?

If I'm wrong and it can be done in 1 step, please point me to the right solution. 
Thanks!

Comment: What #Elasticsearch #version do you use? The answer will be different for versions 6.x (6.8) and 7.x (e.g 7.1).